# Is it possible to make a discord.py bot send a private message to a user without user trigger?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I'm trying to set-up a discord bot that notifies me when various changes happen on a website. I'm using python and discord.py rewrite.

All the examples and tutorials I found required the user to invoke the bot, however I need the bot to rely on external cues(the website getting updated) and not on user interaction.

```py
async def send_notification(content):
    client = discord.Client()
    user = client.fetch_user(0000000)

    if user is not None:
        await user.send(content)
    client.run("TOKEN")
```

I get the following message : RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_notification' was never awaited

Comment: How does your website monitoring work? Does it run on a schedule, or actively monitor the site for changes?

Comment: You could use a **webhook**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form my understanding of the question, a possible solution would be: under on_ready() you could have a while True loop checking this website. Something like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online.")
    while True:
        checkWebsite()
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # Add delay if you want: (takes seconds)
```

Hope this helps :)